# Breadth first search with fixed stopping distance

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm looking at a graph problem where I'm given a source node and need to find all other nodes up to a fixed distance away, where each edge between nodes has a uniform cost. So I've implemented a breadth first search using the standard FIFO queue technique, but stopping the BFS at a fixed distance is causing me problems.

If I were using DFS, I could pass in the current depth with each recursive call, but I can't do that here. I cannot modify the nodes of the graph to keep an extra parameter (distance) either. Any suggestions or references?

Answer (score 3):

Just use two queues and bounce back and forth between them.  Every time you switch from one to the other, increment your depth count by one.

To elaborate...

Maintain an "active" queue and an "inactive" queue.

Pop a node from the active queue.  Add its neighbors to the inactive queue.  Repeat until the active queue is empty.  Then swap the queues.

This maintains the invariant that if the distance to all nodes in the active queue is `d`, the distance to all nodes in the inactive queue is `d+1`. Easy enough to keep track of and stop when you want.

Comment: This sounds great. So basically the first queue holds all the nodes on the frontier at distance d, and the other queue holds the next frontier. I looked in my algorithms textbooks but could not find this approach. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you like my answer, you might consider up voting and/or accepting it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the depth to the value you put in the queue. You can also keep a separate array to store the depth you reached each node.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the vertices you pass together with their distance from the source of the BFS.

Another possibility would be to just mark the vertices in the queue; usually frameworks for graphs allow you to assign weights to elements of the graph, which is a mechanism you could use for your purpose.

One last possibility would be to insert a marking vertex that isn't actually in the graph into the queue after the frontier of one level of the BFS has been completely processed so you know when a new level of BFS depth starts. That would make your queue look something like `v u w x y MARKER s t j l k` with all of these being vertices of the graph, except for `MARKER`.

Comment: Waste of memory to create another data structure to wrap around each vertex?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Edited my answer with two more possibilities.